# How to select elements given the playwright accessiblity snapshot of the page?

Tags: playwright, rpa, playwright-python

How to select an element on page given it's accessibility snapshot?
For example, I want to check the radio button with label "Option 2" which comes after the heading "Q2".

```
{'role': 'WebArea',
 'name': 'random Radio Buttons',
 'children': [{'role': 'heading', 'name': 'random Radio Buttons', 'level': 1},
  {'role': 'link',
   'name': 'Sign in to Google',
   'description': 'Sign in to Google to save your progress. Learn more'},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': ' to save your progress. '},
  {'role': 'button', 'name': 'Learn more'},
  {'role': 'heading', 'name': 'Q1', 'level': 3},
  {'role': 'radio', 'name': 'Option 1', 'disabled': True, 'checked': False},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'Option 1'},
  {'role': 'radio', 'name': 'Option 2', 'disabled': True, 'checked': False},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'Option 2'},
  {'role': 'radio', 'name': 'Option 3', 'disabled': True, 'checked': False},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'Option 3'},
  {'role': 'radio', 'name': 'Option 4', 'disabled': True, 'checked': False},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'Option 4'},
  {'role': 'heading', 'name': 'Q2 ', 'level': 3},
  {'role': 'radio', 'name': 'Option 1', 'disabled': True, 'checked': False},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'Option 1'},
  {'role': 'radio', 'name': 'Option 2', 'disabled': True, 'checked': False},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'Option 2'},
  {'role': 'radio', 'name': 'Option 3', 'disabled': True, 'checked': False},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'Option 3'},
  {'role': 'radio', 'name': 'Option 4', 'disabled': True, 'checked': False},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'Option 4'},
  {'role': 'heading', 'name': 'Q3 ', 'level': 3},
  {'role': 'radio', 'name': 'Option 1', 'disabled': True, 'checked': False},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'Option 1'},
  {'role': 'radio', 'name': 'Option 2', 'disabled': True, 'checked': False},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'Option 2'},
  {'role': 'radio', 'name': 'Option 3', 'disabled': True, 'checked': False},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'Option 3'},
  {'role': 'radio', 'name': 'Option 4', 'disabled': True, 'checked': False},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'Option 4'},
  {'role': 'button', 'name': 'Submit'},
  {'role': 'button', 'name': 'Clear form'},
  {'role': 'text', 'name': 'This form was created inside Felvin. '},
  {'role': 'link', 'name': 'Report Abuse'},
  {'role': 'link', 'name': 'Google \xa0Forms'},
  {'role': 'button', 'name': 'Report a problem to Google'}]}
```

How to get the above accessibility snapshot:

```py
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
playwright = sync_playwright().start()

browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
context = browser.new_context()
page = context.new_page()

url = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdYXqbGlSk38r0L-gyF5HthcjXKs7uK3NXW6QHALL3uqhLgsA/viewform?usp=sf_link'
page.goto(url)
accessibility_snapshot = page.accessibility.snapshot()
```

Comment: Why are you approaching to this using the snapshot instead of the DOM? just curious?

Comment: Have you tried writing some code to traverse the dictionary, find the relevant property, and check the radio button? (if that's in fact what you're trying to do). But yes, this might be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).